# Avoid inserting checkbox into empty cells in forEach loop - Google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of ranges where depending on the cell value, a checked checkbox (Completada) or an unchecked checkbox (No completada) should be inserted.

The problem I have is that the script places checkbox in the entire list of ranges, it does not ignore empty cells or cells that do not contain those specific values.

It's probably a very slight problem, but I can't fix it.

Here is a picture of what I need: [ibb.co/Fq9ssp8](https://ibb.co/Fq9ssp8)

This is my actual code:

```
function checkboxVistaMensual_comparacion() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Calendario');  // Hoja Destino

  var rangesCheckbox = targetSheet.getRangeList(['F6:F98', 'I6:I98', 'L6:L98', 'O6:O98', 'R6:R98', 'U6:U98', 'X6:X98']);
  var rangesCheckboxVal = rangesCheckbox.getRanges();
  
  var c = 'Completada';
  var nc = 'No completada';

  var valores = []
  rangesCheckboxVal.forEach((row)=> {

    if ( row.valueType == SpreadsheetApp.ValueType.CHECKBOX ) return;
    if ( row == '' ) return;

    if ( row == c ){
      valores.push(c);
    } else {
      if ( row == nc ){
      valores.push(nc);
      }
    }

  })  

  rangesCheckbox.insertCheckboxes(c, nc);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample sheet with dummy values for us to easily replicate?

Comment: Also just to confirm, your expected output would be that cells with "Completada" will be replaced by a checked checkbox, and cells with "No completada" will be replaced by a unchecked checkbox, is that correct?

Comment: @CenturyTuna Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that in your script, no processes are done in the forEach loop. I think that this is the reason for your current issue of `the script places checkbox in the entire list of ranges,`.
- I think that in your situation, if you want to insert the checkboxes to the cells of `['F6:F98', 'I6:I98', 'L6:L98', 'O6:O98', 'R6:R98', 'U6:U98', 'X6:X98']` by skipping the cells with the checkbox, "Completada", "No completada" and the empty, the maijor change is required to be done.
- And, in your situation, if the checkbox is put into each cell using RangeList, the process cost becomes high. So, I thought that it might be required to also modify this situation.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function checkboxVistaMensual_comparacion() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Calendario');
  var rangesCheckbox = targetSheet.getRangeList(['F6:F98', 'I6:I98', 'L6:L98', 'O6:O98', 'R6:R98', 'U6:U98', 'X6:X98']);
  var rangesCheckboxVal = rangesCheckbox.getRanges();
  var c = 'Completada';
  var nc = 'No completada';
  rangesCheckboxVal.forEach(r => {
    var values = r.getValues();
    var dataValidations = r.getDataValidations();
    var { dataValidation, values } = values.reduce((o, [v], i) => {
      if (v.toString() != "" && ![c, nc].includes(v) && !(dataValidations[i][0] && dataValidations[i][0].getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX)) {
        o.dataValidation.push([SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox(c, nc).build()]);
        o.values.push([null]);
      } else if (dataValidations[i][0] && dataValidations[i][0].getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX) {
        o.dataValidation.push([dataValidations[i][0]]);
        o.values.push([v]);
      } else {
        o.dataValidation.push([null]);
        o.values.push([v]);
      }
      return o;
    }, { dataValidation: [], values: [] });
    r.setValues(values).setDataValidations(dataValidation);
  });
}
```

- In this script, about the cells of `['F6:F98', 'I6:I98', 'L6:L98', 'O6:O98', 'R6:R98', 'U6:U98', 'X6:X98']`, the checkboxes are put into the cells which have not empty, no values of "Completada" and "No completada", and no checkbox.
- In order to reduce the process cost, in this case, the checkboxes are inserted using `setDataValidations`.

#### Note:

- If you want to change the skipped values, please modify `![c, nc].includes(v)`.

#### References:

- [Class DataValidationBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder)
- [setDataValidations(rules)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setdatavalidationsrules)

### Added:

From your following reply,

> It doesn't work for me either. The code itself is fine, however what I need is that the cells that contain the value "Completado" become checked checkboxes. Cells containing "No completado" become unchecked checkbox. Cells that are empty or have another value, do not insert checkcbox. With your current code, it does nothing.

> And if I remove the phrase indicating ![c, nc].includes(v), then checkboxes are inserted in the cells with "Completada" and "No completada" value, however, the cells with "Completada" value do not stay checked. Here is a picture of what I need: ibb.co/Fq9ssp8

How about the following sample script?

In your script, you use `Completada` and `No completada`. But in your reply, `Completado` and `No completado` are used. In this modification, `Completada` and `No completada` are used. Please be careful about this.

#### Sample script:

```js
function checkboxVistaMensual_comparacion() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Calendario');
  var rangesCheckbox = targetSheet.getRangeList(['F6:F98', 'I6:I98', 'L6:L98', 'O6:O98', 'R6:R98', 'U6:U98', 'X6:X98']);
  var rangesCheckboxVal = rangesCheckbox.getRanges();
  var c = 'Completada';
  var nc = 'No completada';
  rangesCheckboxVal.forEach(r => {
    var values = r.getValues();
    var dataValidation = values.map(([v]) => [[c, nc].includes(v) ? SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox(c, nc).build() : null]);
    r.setDataValidations(dataValidation);
  });
}
```

- By this, the cells with `Completada` and `No completada` from `['F6:F98', 'I6:I98', 'L6:L98', 'O6:O98', 'R6:R98', 'U6:U98', 'X6:X98']` are converted to the checkboxes.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however this is not what I need. It doesn't work for me either. The code itself is fine, however what I need is that the cells that contain the value "Completado" become checked checkboxes. Cells containing "No completado" become unchecked checkbox. Cells that are empty or have another value, do not insert checkcbox. With your current code, it does nothing.

Comment: And if I remove the phrase indicating `![c, nc].includes(v)`, then checkboxes are inserted in the cells with "Completada" and "No completada" value, however, the cells with "Completada" value do not stay checked. Here is a picture of what I need: https://ibb.co/Fq9ssp8

Comment: @Nerea Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your reply, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question again, I apologize again.

Comment: Indeed, now it works perfectly! Mark your answer as solved. The difference from "Completada" to "Completado" is by the translator. Unfortunately my English is very basic and a translator helped me :)  I didn't know how to get the values ​​of a range list, now with your code it's clear to me. A doubt. What does the "v" mean in the map function? I'm new to javascript and I don't quite understand many basic terms. I'm basically learning through trial and error.

Comment: @Nerea Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `v` of `values.map(([v]) =>`, in this case, `values` is a 2-dimensional array. Here, `v` is a value in the array of each element of the 2-dimensional array. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) For example, when `values` is `[["a1"], ["b1"],,,]`, `v` is `a1`, `a2`,,,. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: This explanation was great and very easy to understand! Thank you very much for all your help.